# count each rows with codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, count

i have two tables
table topik and table dosen

```
dosen table---->|dosen_id|dosen_nama|     topik---->|dosen_id1|dosen_id2|
                   1         a                           1       2
                   2         b                           2       1
                   3         c                           1       3
```

i want count rows dosen_id1 and dosen_id2 as a results like this

```
|dosen_nama|count|
      a       3
      b       2
      c       1
```

what code in model i must write?
please help me...

**UPDATE**

This is my controller

```
$data['jumlah'] = $this->topikdo_model->get_all_topikdo_jumlah();
```

This is my view

```
<table class="table table-bordered  table-striped  table-hover ">
        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <th>SANDOS</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Jumlah Bimbingan</th>
                <th>Aksi</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $no=1;
            foreach($daftardosen as $row)
            {
            ?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $row->dosen_id;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->dosen_nama;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $jumlah;?></td>
                <td align='center'>

                    <?php
                    echo anchor('topikdo_controller/rincian_daftardosen/'.$row->dosen_id,'Rincian');
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php $no++;
            }
            ?>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

i have writen query in model like rohini sugested
model

```
$sql="SELECT d.dosen_nama, count(t.a) 
  FROM dosen as d, (Select topik_pembimbing1 as a 
                    FROM topik 
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT topik_pembimbing2 as a 
                    FROM topik) as t 
  WHERE d.dosen_id = t.a 
  GROUP BY d.dosen_nama"; 
$data=$this->db->query($sql);return $data->result();
```

But there was message error "array to string conversion"...
i am sorry,,, i dont have any connection to the internet few days ago...

Comment: is it right your desired result ?

Comment: Please post your code you have attempted so we can see where you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply execute a query to get the desired result.

```
SELECT dosen_nama, ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM topik WHERE dosen_id1=d.dosen_id) +  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM topik WHERE dosen_id2=d.dosen_id)) AS COUNT
FROM dosen d
```

Comment: i have message array to string conversion with your query Adeel

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query in your model.....!

```
SELECT d.dosen_nama, count(t.a) 
FROM dosen as d, (Select dosen_id1 as a 
                  FROM topik 
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT dosen_id2 as a 
                  FROM topik) as t 
WHERE d.dosen_id = t.a 
GROUP BY d.dosen_nama
```

**UPDATE:**

You have written,

```
$sql="SELECT d.dosen_nama, count(t.a) 
      FROM dosen as d, (Select topik_pembimbing1 as a 
                        FROM topik 
                        UNION ALL 
                        SELECT topik_pembimbing2 as a 
                        FROM topik) as t 
      WHERE d.dosen_id = t.a 
      GROUP BY d.dosen_nama"; 

$data=$this->db->query($sql); 
return $data->result();
```

The last line of your code will return you an query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure.

I suspect you are trying to use this array where you need to use a string.
Since the array is attempted to be parsed as a string you might be getting this error.

Comment: i have writed this code, but i have notice=array to string conversion.     $sql="SELECT d.dosen_nama, count(t.a) FROM dosen as d, (Select topik_pembimbing1 as a FROM topik UNION ALL SELECT topik_pembimbing2 as a FROM topik) as t WHERE d.dosen_id = t.a GROUP BY d.dosen_nama";
$data=$this->db->query($sql);
return $data->result();

Comment: Can you please brief the problem you are facing..
Please post some more code so that i may provide you some more help...

Comment: so what must i write in return of model and show the data in view?

Comment: line '<td><?php echo $jumlah;?></td>' rohini

Comment: Check if the $jumlah contains an array.....
Try printing jumlah's resultset in view using print_r($jumlah); and see what u get there..

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [dosen_nama] => HARITS AR ROSYID [count] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [dosen_nama] => MUHAMAMAD JAUHARUL FUADI [count] => 1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [dosen_nama] => M. ZAINAL ARIFIN [count] => 0 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [dosen_nama] => TRIYANNA WIDYANINGTYAS [count] => 1 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [dosen_nama] => MOHAMMAD ASHAR [count] => 0 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [dosen_nama] => DIDIK DWI PRASETYA [count] => 1 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [dosen_nama] => ILHAM ARI ELBAIT ZAENI [count] => 0 ) ) )